# jQuery smoothly transition from default image to another image then another

Tags: jquery

I have a unordered list of images with the first li having a "display: list-item" and the rest having a "display: none".

What I want to do is have a smooth transition that fades in the second image then the third without the appearance of a break.

The following jsFiddle shows what I have at the minute, notice there is a break in the fade between the second and third image fade.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6hUr/

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could experiment with different easing functions, the standard one is "swing", you could try "linear"

```
$('#enter').click(function() {
    $('#slide2').fadeIn(1000, 'linear', function(){
        $('#slide3').fadeIn(1000, 'linear');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6hUr/1/
​
If you use jqueryui there are more easing functions you could try

Answer (score 0):

I hope you like this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6hUr/4/

I'd try to implement some animation overlapping.